# My first RoR Gem: NameError in MicropostsController#up_vote uninitialized constant VoterLove::Voter::Vote

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm working on my first RubyGem [voter_love](https://github.com/ramz15/voter_love). When I install the Gem and use the up_vote method I get this error:

`NameError in MicropostsController#up_vote 
uninitialized constant VoterLove::Voter::Vote`

Do I need to generate an initializer or require the Gem somewhere in my code to initialize the Votes model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](https://github.com/ramz15/voter_love/blob/master/lib/voter_love/votes.rb), your model is `VoterLove::Votes` not `VoterLove::Voter::Vote`.

And a simple advice: simply adopt a normal Rails app architecture and use the Engine power to have everything painlessly included (models, controllers, views...).

Comment: consider +1 when an answer is useful :)

Answer (score 1):

You've most likely referred to a class or module that doesn't exist. Most likely, you've forgotten to require a gem or library needed for the code to work, or you've made a typo. Another possibility is that the class you'd like to refer to is in another module. If that's the case, you'll have to refer to it with its full name as in the following code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

module MyModule
 class MyClass; end
end

c = MyModule::MyClass.new
```